# SSL through Apache Proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy

I have a server running lots of virtual machines, but only one public IP (and absolutely no way to obtain more). Many of these VMs use port 80 to display web content. At the moment, I use different ports to access these WebUIs, such as mydomain.com:9000, mydomain.com:7000, and so on.

What I want is to have subdomains, more like service1.mydomain.com, service2.mydomain.com...So I create a proxy VM onto which I redirect everything coming from port 80 and redirecting to internal IPs based on what the subdomain is.

Now my problem is the following: I have an SSL certificate from mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com. How can I set it up so the proxy propagates it? To me, the solutions are:

- the certificate is on the proxy, so the proxy does this: 
  internal VM:http ---> proxy: http to https ----> outer world: https
- the certificate is on the VM hosting the service and the proxy does not propagate the certificate, so the proxy does this:
  internal VM: https ---> proxy https to http ---> outer world: http
- the certificate is on the VM hosting the service and the proxy propagate the certificate, so the proxy does this:
  internal VM: https ---> proxy: https ---> outer world: https

I'd prefer the last solution, but I don't know how to set it up on both Apaches, knowing that Apache on SSL-enabled VMs is configured as is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        TransferLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/transfer.log
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request.log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to understand your line of thoughts since you describe things the opposite way of what is common. Usually one describes a web service as seen from the outside, not from the inside. Anyway, I do not really see your problem here: in my words you have a frontend server that is accessed by clients, either by http or by https. That server has the certificate for https. Fine. What internal resources that server queries, the file system or an internal backend server, is invisible to the client. So what is the problem here?

Comment: The only problem here is that you _can not_ use subdomains for the various separate web service on your VMs, since your certificate is only valid for the domain itself and the www subdomain, if I got you right. If so, then there is no way around this if you want to use https. You can only offer those services under a path under your domain for https in that case, or you will have to deal with a non matching certificate.

Comment: So knowing that I have a proxy that routes HTTP data to VMs based on subdomain, where should I put my certificate: on the proxy or on the virtual machine that hosts the service?

Comment: When talking about http a certificate does not make sense. When talking about https, then the certificate makes only sense on that host that serves the domain the certificate is valid for, so the domain itself or the www subdomain. For all other subdomains it simply is not valid.

Comment: in 99% of all scenarios it should make sense to install the certificate on the frontend server.

Comment: So you think I should to something like VM(http)------> PROXY(http->https)----------->outer world(https) (so the ssl certificate part is on the proxy) ?

Comment: Ah, now we are getting closer. Exactly! (only as said: usually it is described the other way around, since http is not pushing. It is a pull protocol). So: client (browser) > [https] > frontend server ("proxy") > [http] > backend server ("VM")

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun! (and respect primitive life forms!)

Comment: @arkascha : lol I respect all life forms :D

Comment: Let me hug you! *handshake*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79165/discussion-between-deadbird-and-arkascha).